# How To Create Subreport and connect with main report in acumatica report designer

Tags: erp, acumatica, report-designer

i have **1 head table**, and **2 detail tables**. i want to create report like [image: Screenshoot Report]

But i have problem to show material data and i try using **subreport**, material data still not show.
Am I proceeding in the right way or else what should I do? Please help and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Which table is the header, and which is the details?  How do you link the details, to the header?  What are the relationships?